# Slide divs in overflow container then remove the first element and attach it to the end

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Right now when I add `.appendTo(".wrapper")` like in the below code it takes away the animation effect. In the final result I would like it so that when the div at the most left side  slides  out of view (overflow hidden effect) it should be removed but added to the end of the slide so there could be continues slide show effect.repeating the prior divs.

```
   $(document).ready( function(){
        var x = 0;
        $(".next").on("click", function(){
            x -= 245;
            // $(".wrapper").css({"marginLeft" : x +"px"}).delay(3000).queue(function(next){
            //  $(this).css({"marginLeft" : 0})
            //  $(".element").eq(0).appendTo(".wrapper")
            //  next();
            // })
            console.log($(".element").length)
            $(".element").each(function(i, e){
                console.log(i)
                $(this).eq(i).css({"marginLeft" : x +"px"}).appendTo(".wrapper");
            })
            // $(".element").eq(0).css({"marginLeft" : x +"px"}).appendTo(".wrapper")

        })
    });
```

css:

```
    .mgcont{
        margin:5% auto;
        width:970px;
        overflow: hidden;
        border: 2px solid gray;
    }
    .wrapper{
        /*overflow: hidden;*/

        white-space: nowrap;
        width:960px;

    }
    .element{
        width: 240px;
        height: 300px;
        background: tomato;
        display: inline-block;
        margin-left: 10px;
        transition: margin 3s;
    }
    .prev{
        float: right;
    }
```

html:

```
<div class="mgcont">
    <button class="next">next</button>
    <button class="prev">PREV</button>
    <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="element">1</div>
        <div class="element">2</div>
        <div class="element">3</div>
        <div class="element">4</div>
        <div class="element">5</div>
        <div class="element">6</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/b8asu2rn/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to modify your javascript like this

```
        $(document).ready( function(){
        $(".next").on("click", function(){
            console.log($(".element").length)
            $(".element").each(function(i, e){
                console.log(i)
            })
                $(".element").eq(0).css({"margin-left" : "-245px"}).delay(3000).queue(function(next){
                    $(this).appendTo(".wrapper").css({"margin-left":"10px"});
$( this ).dequeue();
});
        });
    });
```

Also modify css for transition property as

```
.element{
        width: 240px;
        height: 300px;
        background: tomato;
        display: inline-block;
        margin-left: 10px;
        transition: margin-left 3s;
    }
```

This will work perfectly

[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Anknit/b8asu2rn/2/)

If you want to achieve it with a separate css class, you have to do like this

```
$(document).ready( function(){
        $(".next").on("click", function(){
            console.log($(".element").length)
            $(".element").each(function(i, e){
                console.log(i)
            })
                $(".element").eq(0).addClass('translateleft').delay(3000).queue(function(next){$(this).appendTo(".wrapper").removeClass('translateleft');
$( this ).dequeue();
});
        });
    });
```

and in your css define styles for class `translateleft` like this

```
   .translateleft{
    animation: translateleft 3s;
    -webkit-animation:translateleft 3s;
    -moz-animation:translateleft 3s;
    -o-animation:translateleft 3s;
}
@keyframes translateleft{
    from{margin-left:0px;}
    to{margin-left:-245px;}
}
@-webkit-keyframes translateleft{
    from{margin-left:0px;}
    to{margin-left:-245px;}
}
@-moz-keyframes translateleft{
    from{margin-left:0px;}
    to{margin-left:-245px;}
}
@-o-keyframes translateleft{
    from{margin-left:0px;}
    to{margin-left:-245px;}
}
```

To see working example [See Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Anknit/b8asu2rn/4/)

**UPDATE**
 `.dequeue()` statement was missing from the function .
Now the answer has been updated and works perfectly for repetitions

Comment: I like this but my mind was thinking to change the margin left of the element or add a class of translate along the x axis but I'm starting to think that reducing the width to 0 is better. I'm going to  allow sometime before accepting the answer because maybe someone will provide one with the methods i just mentioned. Thanks

Comment: I have implemented the same using margin property. You can see updated answer.
Also the fiddle link has been updated to see the implementation

Comment: Sorry to bother you but i just realized that in the http://jsfiddle.net/Anknit/b8asu2rn/1/ you provided and in the other one  the slide show stops prematurely. In the fiddle you can see that on the second time around, you cant go past the second slide when I click the next button. can you fix it? Sathish's answer works.

Comment: Did you see these [jsfiddle.net/Anknit/b8asu2rn/2](https://jsfiddle.net/Anknit/b8asu2rn/2)  and [https://jsfiddle.net/Anknit/b8asu2rn/4] (jsfiddle.net/Anknit/b8asu2rn/4) . Does the problem still persist ?

Comment: I just checked the 2 links you mentioned and I can confirm that the problem still persists. the slides don't make 2 full cycle.. in http://jsfiddle.net/Anknit/b8asu2rn/2/ it stops at the 2nd slide and in the other one (http://jsfiddle.net/Anknit/b8asu2rn/4/)it jumps to the beginning when it's at the end and the button has no effect. If you decide to fix it please keep the order of the divs in the html in place Sathish put the first div at the end. I'd like to see one working where the order is intact. Thank you

Comment: `.dequeue()` statement was missing from the function .
Now the answer has been updated and works perfectly for repetitions
Watch [here](http://jsfiddle.net/Anknit/b8asu2rn/6/)

Answer (score 1):

I modified all files, just try the below snippets,

```js
   $(function(){
  var width = $('.element:first').width();   
$(".next").on("click", function(){
    var neww = $(".element:first").clone();
    $('.element').eq(1).css({'margin-left':'-'+width+'px'});
     $(".element:first").remove();
    neww.appendTo('.wrapper');        
   $('.element:last').css({'margin-left':'5px'});
});
$(".prev").on("click", function(){
    var neww = $('.element:last').clone();
    $(".element:last").remove();
     $('.element:first').css({'margin-left':'5px'});
    neww.prependTo('.wrapper');
    $('.element:first').css({'margin-left':'-'+width+'px'});
});
 });
```

```css
   .mgcont{
    margin:5% auto;
    width:970px;
    overflow: hidden;
    border: 2px solid gray;
}
.wrapper{
    /*overflow: hidden;*/

    white-space: nowrap;
    width:960px;

}
.element:first-child{
    margin-left: -240px;
}
.element{
    width: 240px;
    height: 300px;
    background: tomato;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-left: 5px;
    transition: all 3s;
}
.prev{
    float: right;
}
```

```html
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
   <div class="mgcont">
<button class="next">next</button>
<button class="prev">PREV</button>
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="element">6</div>
  <div class="element">1</div>
  <div class="element">2</div>
  <div class="element">3</div>
  <div class="element">4</div>
  <div class="element">5</div>      
</div>
  </div>
```

I hope this will work as you excepted,

Working **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/7vwhyc4z/)**